# 1:n disable constraints for the n-side?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

### The Problem

I have a 1:n relation, but the n side shouldnt rely on constraints. So i actually wanna insert a EntityPojo via its future id, when its not saved yet ( Lets ignore that its a bad practice ). This looks kinda like this.

```java
var relation = new RelationshipPojo();
.
.
.
relation.targets.add(session.getReference(futureID, EntityPojo.class));
session.save(relation);

// A few frames later
session.save(theEntityPojoWithTheSpecificId);
```

Cascading is not possible here, i only have its future ID, not a reference to the object i wanna save. Only its id it will have in the future.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "relationship")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class RelationshipPojo {

    .
    .
    .

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public Set<EntityPojo> targets = new LinkedHashSet<>();
}
```

### Question

How do we tell hibernate that it should ignore the constraints for this 1:n "target" relation ? It should just insert the given ID into the database, ignoring if that EntityPojo really exists yet.

Glad for any help on this topic, thanks !

Comment: On SQL level this can be done easily. The referenced column on the side `N` is defined as NULLable. So it can be assigned with definite value (in this case the same value must exist on the side `1`) or with NULL (of course in this case this row is referred to nothing). Search the documentation how this is implemented in Hibernate.

Comment: If your question is whether we can insert an `id` on the owning-side (`n`-side) that is not yet present on the referenced side (`1`-side), then the answer is yes, this is possible. But we have to remove / not define the foreign key constraint on the owning side. Furthermore, I am quite sure that this is not supported by JPA.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what it is you're trying to accomplish, exactly? Insert rows into the join table, without inserting anything into the `ENTITY_POJO` table?

Comment: @crizzis Exactly. Inserting a row into .targets without constraints. Without having a foreign key exception because the entity doesnt exist yet.

Comment: See my answer, then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For a much simpler solution, see the EDIT below**

If the goal is to insert rows into the join table, without affecting the `ENTITY_POJO` table, you could model the many-to-many association as an entity itself:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "relationship")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class RelationshipPojo {

    @OneToMany(cascade = PERSIST, fetch = EAGER, mappedBy = "relationship")
    public Set<RelationShipEntityPojo> targets = new LinkedHashSet<>();
}

@Entity
public class RelationShipEntityPojo {

    @Column(name = "entity_id")
    private Long entityId;

    @ManyToOne
    private RelationshipPojo relationship;

    @ManyToOne
    @NotFound(action = IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private EntityPojo entity;
}
```

This way, you'll be able to set a value to the `entityId` property to a non-existent id, and if an `EntityPojo` by that id is later inserted, Hibernate will know how to populate `relationship` properly. The caveat is a more complicated domain model, and the fact that you will need to control the association between `RelationshipEntityPojo` and `EntityPojo` using the `entityId` property, **not** `entity`.

EDIT Actually, disregard the above answer, it's overly complicated. Turing85 is right in that you should simply remove the constraint. You can prevent Hibernate from generating it in the first place using:

```
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "target_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "none", value = ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT)))
    public Set<EntityPojo> targets = new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

The only caveat is that when you try to load `RelationshipPojo.targets` before inserting the missing `EntityPojo`, Hibernate will complain about the missing entity, as apparently `@NotFound` is ignored for `@ManyToMany`.

Comment: Thanks, im gonna try that out ! Do you know if its somehow possible without an extra pojo ? ^^

Comment: See my edited answer. I feel dumb now, sorry for the confusion